# Wrong concept in Fubini's Theorem (Stronger form)

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

Example: Find the volume of the prism whose base is the triangle in the $xy-plane$ bounded by the $x- axis$ and the lines $y=x$  and $x=1$ and whose top lies in the plane

> $z = f(x,y) = 3-x-y$

The above is an example from my text book. The answer, of course, is to use the Fubini's Theorem (Stronger form). i.e. Set either $y-limits$ or $x-limits$ of integration as a function x or y respectively. The remaining one will be a constant.

> [image: image1] and I understand it.

Now, given the question, I can literally picture the base region in my head with specific limits of integration. i.e. both (x-limits and y-limits) are from 0 to

But, WHY can't I compute [image: image2]

(As the above gives 2 instead of 1)

Please help me to clear my concept T.T

Comment: From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As iterated integrals it is abundantly clear that

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x f(x,y) \, dy \right)\, dx \neq \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dy \right)\, dx, $$

the left being the volume of the prism with triangular base and the right being the larger volume of the prism with the square base.

If you are bringing up Fubini here, it would appear you are trying to reconcile the iterated integrals with the Riemann integral over a general region in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The basic definition of the Riemann integral is restricted to rectangular regions. It is extended for our triangular base $T \subset [0,1]^2$, say,  using the indicator function $\chi_T$ according to

$$\int_T f = \int_{[0,1]^2} f \chi_T$$

Now Fubini's theorem implies

$$\int_T f = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y) \chi_T\, dy \right)\, dx = \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x f(x,y) \, dy \right)\, dx $$